# Semicolon usage in this sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

A person who is a big fan of big pop star finds a cardboard poster of that celebrity  takes a picture of himself with the cardboard. And says,

> 'Since chances of meeting my idol in this life are dim. This shall do; provide the satisfaction.'

Comment: If you ever hear anyone speaking like that; run.

Comment: *Provide the satisfaction* doesn't make any sense. It could be a sentence on its own, but it still doesn't make sense. *Satisfaction* isn't something that's been mentioned before. What satisfaction? Perhaps something like this: *Since chances of meeting my idol in this life are dim, this shall do; I am satisfied.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's bad writing, plain and simple.

I think the text is trying to say this:

> Since chances of meeting my idol in this life are dim, I'll have to be satisfied with this.

However, there are serious punctuation problems in the original. First, this is not a complete sentence, so it shouldn't end with period:

> Since chances of meeting my idol in this life are dim.

although it could be made a full sentence my taking out the first word:

> Chances of meeting my idol in this life are dim.

Second, semicolons are used to separate complete sentences that are [closely related in theme](https://writersrelief.com/2008/03/16/three-essential-semicolon-rules/). As one writer's website explains:

> Example: *Tom earned his bachelor’s degree last summer; his sister earned hers in the fall*.
>
> > These sentences are related thematically; both discuss academic degrees and when they were earned, so the semicolon is appropriate. Of course, a period would also be appropriate.

The three words:

> This shall do.

is a complete sentence, albeit a brief one. So is:

> Provide the satisfaction.

although, as a standalone sentence, it's a command to provide satisfaction. The way it is worded, this sentence has nothing to do with the selfie with the poster, even with the semicolon. Punctuation alone can't change the meaning of that sentence.

I can think of ways to use a semicolon correctly in this context, but I'm not going to provide it here, because it seems too likely that I'd be doing your homework for you.

The only context I can think of where what you've written would make any sense at all is where you've been given an exercise telling you to use a semicolon in sentence. (If I'm right about that, I don't mind telling you that you need to try again, but I'm not going to provide the answer outright. If that assumption is wrong, however, feel free to edit your question to provide more background information and context, and perhaps I'll edit my answer as well.)

Comment: Thank you for the amazing explaination. Okay, I spill the beans this is a photo that I took and this is the caption I was trying to write. English isn't my first language but that shouldn't be an excuse, because I passed highschool exams studying it. But not speaking regularly does seems to have taken a toll. So, i wanted to get myself checked rather than blatantly sharing incorrect sentences

Comment: With 'provide the satisfaction' part I am trying to say that poster / the event of the selfie is providing the satisfaction

Comment: @user6177394 - Fair enough. I'd word it like this: _I'll never meet my idol in real life; I'll have to be content with the poster for now._

Comment: that is not creative enough. That's like saying a blatant thought.

Comment: @user6177394 - You can try to be more literary, sublime, or creative, but _provide the satisfaction_ is not the phrase you're looking for. Nevertheless, your question seemed to be more about semicolon usage than creative writing, so you can take it from here.